# When is it advantageous to use theano's scan function

Tags: theano

I've been reading the Theano documentation on scan and find myself confused by two, seemingly, contradictory statements.

On http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/loop.html#scan, one of the advantages of scan is listed as:

```
Slightly faster than using a for loop in Python with a compiled Theano function.
```

But, on http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html#lib-scan, in a section on optimizing the use of scan, it says:

```
 Scan makes it possible to define simple and compact graphs that can do
 the same work as much larger and more complicated graphs. However, it 
 comes with a significant overhead. As such, **when performance is the 
 objective, a good rule of thumb is to perform as much of the computation 
 as possible outside of Scan**. This may have the effect of increasing 
 memory usage but can also reduce the overhead introduces by using Scan.
```

My reading of 'performance', here, is as a synonym for speed. So, I'm left confused as to when/if scan will lead to shorter runtimes, once compilation has been completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expression intrinsically needs a for-loop, then you sometimes have two options:

1. Build the expression using a python for loop
2. Build the expression using scan

Option 1 only works if you know in advance the length of your for-loop. It can happen that the length of your for-loop depends on a symbolic variable that is not available at script-writing time. In that case you need to use scan. Although oftentimes you can formulate the problem either way (see the absence of scan in tensorflow).

As for time performance, there have been a number of results showing that it really depends on the problem which one is faster.

Comment: In the case of a symbolic variable whose value is unavailable at script writing time, wouldn't there be some way to replace that variable with a theano function that would calculate the value of that variable at run time?